# Ajax Requests With Django Views - Incorrectly Capturing Variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I've been passing data successfully from my urls to my views with other samples of code, so I'm not sure why this one is any different, but here's what I have for an ajax call to a view. I'm trying to pass the id and an optional parameter of depth :

### links/urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('links.ajax',
     url(r'^ajax/(?P<id>\d+)*$', 'ajax_graph_request', name='ajax_graph_request'),
)
```

### links/ajax.py

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def ajax_graph_request(request, id):
   depth = request.GET.get('depth','1') 
   result = {'id':id, 'depth':depth}
   data = json.dumps(result)
   return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

### the request

```
console.log(record);
$.getJSON("/ajax/", { id:record, depth:2 }).done(function( data ){
    console.log(data);
});
```

### the response

```
22145 (from js console print)
{"depth": "2", "id": null}
```

So the request is being propogated correctly to the right view, but the variable isn't. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL patterns is `ajax/(?P<id>\d+)` that is, the view `ajax_graph_request` expects an `id`  as a parameter. By sending it as a data argument `{ id:record, depth:2 }`. it is passed as a `kwarg` rather than a parameter `id`.

Change the `.getJson` method to

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/"+record, { depth:2 }).done(function( data )
```

It would work fine.

Comment: Sweet! Exactly as prescribed. I guess I was too caught up in the idea that (?<varname>regex) would mean that in the url dispatcher, it'd be looking for a ?varname= declaration, instead of simply matching the regex and passing the variable name to the view.